# Multi files upload in Symfony2?

Tags: php, file, symfony, upload

I spent nearly 2 months on this issue : How to handle multi files upload on Symfony2?
I tried many Bundles, many solutions, but nothing really works.

So, I would like to know if it's possible to give me some help.

**Here's my Entity File :**

```
<?php

namespace Monitoring\IdocBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * Sap3a13Feuil1
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Monitoring\IdocBundle\Entity\Sap3a13Feuil1Repository")
 */
class Sap3a13Feuil1
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="Delivery", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $delivery;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="Statut", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $statut;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="IDocNumber", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $iDocNumber;

    /**
     * @var DateTime $createDate
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="CreateDate", type="datetime")
     */
    private $createDate;

    /**
     * @var DateTime $createHours
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="CreateHours", type="datetime")
     */
    private $createHours;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="Text_status", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $textStatus;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="Param1", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $param1;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="Param2", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $param2;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="URL", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $url;

    /**
     * @Assert\File(maxSize="6000000000000")
     */
    public $file = array();


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->createDate  = new \Datetime;
        $this->createHours = new \Datetime;
    }

    // GETTERS AND SETTERS

    public function setFile(UploadedFile $file)
    {
        $this->file = $file;
    }

    /**
     * Get url
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getUrl()
    {
        return $this->url;
    }

    public function getFile()
    {
        return $this->file;
    }

    public function upload()
    {
    // Si jamais il n'y a pas de fichier (champ facultatif)
        if (null === $this->file) {
            return;
        }

                // On garde le nom original du fichier de l'internaute
                $name = $this->file->getClientOriginalName();

                // On déplace le fichier envoyé dans le répertoire de notre choix
                $this->file->move($this->getUploadRootDir(), $name);

                // On sauvegarde le nom de fichier dans notre attribut $url
                $this->url = $name;

                unset($this->file);
    }

    public function getUploadDir()
    {
        // On retourne le chemin relatif vers l'image pour un navigateur
        return 'uploads/img';
    }

    protected function getUploadRootDir()
    {
        // On retourne le chemin relatif vers l'image pour notre code PHP
        return __DIR__.'/../../../../web/'.$this->getUploadDir();
    }


}
```

**And there is my form in my FileType:**

```
    <?php

namespace Monitoring\IdocBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;

class Sap3a13Feuil1Type extends AbstractType
{
        /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

        $builder
            ->add('file', 'file', array(
                'data_class' => null,
                'label' => 'Fichiers',
                'attr' => array(
                    'multiple' => true,
                    ))
            )
            ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Monitoring\IdocBundle\Entity\Sap3a13Feuil1'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'monitoring_idocbundle_sap3a13feuil1';
    }
}
```

**My controller :**

```
    <?php

namespace Monitoring\IdocBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Monitoring\IdocBundle\Entity\Sap3a13Feuil1;
use Monitoring\IdocBundle\Form\Sap3a13Feuil1Type;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;

class UploadController extends Controller{

    public function uploadAction()
    {

        // On crée un objet Sap3a13Feuil1
        $Sap3a13Feuil1 = new Sap3a13Feuil1();

        $file = [$Sap3a13Feuil1];var_dump($file);

        // On ajoute les champs de l'entité que l'on veut à notre formulaire
        $form = $this->createForm(new Sap3a13Feuil1Type, $Sap3a13Feuil1);

        //on récupère la requête
        $request = $this->get('request');
        //on vérifie que la requête est de type POST
        if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST'){


            //on fait le lien entre la requête et le formulaire
            //a partir de maintenant, la variable $Sap3a13Feuil1
            //contiendra les valeurs entrées
            $form->bind($request);

            //on vérifie que les valeurs entrées sont correctes
            if($form->isValid()){

                    $Sap3a13Feuil1->upload();
                    //si le formulaire est valide
                    //on enregistre l'objet dans la BDD
                    //$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                    //$em->persist($Sap3a13Feuil1);
                    //$em->flush();

                //on redirige vers la page habituelle
                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('monitoring_idoc_flow'));
            }
        }

    return $this->render('MonitoringIdocBundle:Default:upload.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }


    /**public function uploadAction()
    {
        $request = $this->getRequest();


        $editId = $this->getRequest()->get('editId');

        if(!preg_match('/^\d+$/', $editId))
        {
            $editId = sprintf('%09d', mt_rand(0,1999999999));
            if($Sap3a13Feuil1->getId())
            {
                $this->get('punk_ave.file_uploader')->syncFiles(
                    array('from_folder' => 'attachments/'.$Sap3a13Feuil1->getId(),
                        'to_folder' => 'tmp/attachments/'.$editId,
                        'create_to_folder' => true));
            }
        }

        $fileUploader = $this->get('punk_ave.file_uploader');
        $fileUploader->syncFiles(
            array('from_folder' => '/tmp/attachments/'.$editId,
                'remove_from_folder' => true,
                'create_to_folder' =>true));
    }**/
}
```

**And, finally, my view (where I call my form) :**

```
<tr>
    <td><form action="{{ path('monitoring_idoc_flow') }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }} {{ form_widget(form) }} </td>
    <td><p><input type="submit"/></p></td>
        </form>
</tr>
```

If anyone could help me, it would be very nice. Thank you !

Comment: Welcome To Stack OverFlow.. Please provide only those information which is needed

Answer (score 2):

If it were me (and I have done this), I would use [collections](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html). So, all you need to do is create a generic `FileUploadType` form, with the `buildForm` looking like this...

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder->add('field_name', 'file', array(
        'label' => 'Some Label',
    )
}
```

Then, I personally had another entity to keep track of all my files uploaded, so I can check ownership etc. See [this article](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html) in the documentation, it's pretty straight forward.

From there on, in the form you want to upload from, you just declare a field as such (in the `formBuilder` method:

```
//...
->add('your_field_name_here', 'collection', array(
    'type' => new FileUploadType(),
    'allow_add' => true, //etc etc
    //...
)
```

and that should work if your main entity has a `OneToMany` relationship with the new "file" entity you created.

***EDIT*** Oh, if you DO use my method of adding another entity to keep track of your files, don't forget to do this in the `FileUploadType`:

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver) {
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Path\To\Your\Bundle\Entity\FileUpload'
    ));
}
```

Comment: Hi, first, I would like to thank you. But I already have a FileUploadType (named FileType in my example). Did you mean that I sould modify my form just like this : 

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder->add('field_name', 'file', array(
        'label' => 'Some Label',
    ))
    ->add('your_field_name_here', 'collection', array(
    'type' => new FileUploadType(),
    'allow_add' => true,));

Because I do this but I don't think it's the good solution.

Answer (score 0):

I try to explain you, how i did it. I have an Company entity, which can contain 0 to n CompanyImages. CompanyImage is an entity, which contains 1 image file.

In the CompanyImageType I have following:

```
class CompanyImageType extends AbstractType {

  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {

    $builder->add('file', 'file', array('required' => false, 'label' => 'image.file.label'));
  }

  public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver) {
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'AMSDev\fnpBundle\Entity\CompanyImage'
    ));
  }....
```

then I have a CompanyImage entity, which contains only one file (not array of them)

```
class CompanyImage {

  /**
   * @ORM\Id
   * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
   * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
   */
  protected $id;

  /**
   * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
   */
  protected $path;

  /**
   * Image file
   *
   * @var File
   *
   * @Assert\File(
   *     maxSize = "1M",
   *     mimeTypes = {"image/jpeg", "image/gif", "image/png", "image/tiff"},
   *     maxSizeMessage = "The maxmimum allowed file size is 1MB.",
   *     mimeTypesMessage = "Only the filetypes image are allowed..."
   * )
   */
  protected $file;

  /**
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Company", inversedBy="images")
   * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="company_id", referencedColumnName="id")
   */
  protected $company;

...
```

In the Company entity I have then

```
class Company {
....
  /**
   * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="CompanyImage", mappedBy="company", cascade={"persist"})
   */
  protected $images;
...
```

and CompanyType contains then the collections of CompanyImageType-s

```
class CompanyType extends AbstractType {

  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    parent::buildForm($builder, $options);

    $factory = $builder->getFormFactory();

    $builder->add('name')
            ....
            ->add('images', 'collection', array(
            'type' => new CompanyImageType(),
            'allow_add' => true,
            'by_reference' => false,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'prototype' => true
            )
            ...
```

You need some javascript programming in the twigs then of course. Hope that helped.